# Show ideals are equal

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals

> Blockquote

Let $k$ be a field. Let $I \subset k[x_1,...,x_n]$ be an ideal and let $f_1,...,f_s \in k[x_1,...,x_n]$.

Using the fact that the following are equivalent

i) $f_1,...,f_s \in I$

ii) $\langle f_1,...,f_s \rangle \subset I$

show that $\langle 2x^2+3y^2-11,x^2-y^2-3\rangle = \langle x^2-4,y^2-1\rangle$.

I have the following:

$2(x^2-4)+3(y^2-1)=2x^2+3y^2-11 \in \langle x^2-4,y^2-1\rangle$

and

$x^2-4-(y^2-1)=x^2-y^2-3 \in \langle x^2-4,y^2-1\rangle$

Thus by stated fact, I have the inclusion $\langle 2x^2+3y^2-11,x^2-y^2-3\rangle \subset \langle x^2-4,y^2-1\rangle$.

Comment: $2(x^2-4) -3(y^2 - 1) = 2x^2 - 3y^2 - 5$ though...

Comment: @Arthur thanks, I missed that. Devilathor, thanks I will try that.

Comment: It appears that $-11$ should be $-5\ \ $

Comment: @lukeskywalker Sorry, I tried to finishes my hint but it led to a non-consistent system. (That's why I've erased it).

Comment: @Devilathor Thanks. I fixed my mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint** $\,\ \left[\begin{array}{rr} \color{#0a0}2 & \color{#c00}{3} \\ 1 & -1\end{array}\right] \overbrace{\left[\begin{array}{r} x^2-4\\ y^2-1\end{array}\right]}^{\large f_{\large i}} = \overbrace{\left[\begin{array}{r} 2x^2-3y^2-5\\ x^2-y^2-3\end{array}\right]}^{\large g_{\large i}}\ $ and it is invertible, having determinant $\ne 0$.

The above shows $\,g_1 = \color{#0a0}2f_1+\color{#c00}{3}f_2 \in \langle f_1,f_2\rangle\,$ and $\,g_2 = f_1 - f_2 \in \langle f_1,f_2\rangle,\ $ so $\ \langle g_1,g_2\rangle\subseteq \langle f_1,f_2\rangle.\,$ Conversely, multiplying by the inverse of the matrix, shows that the $\,f_i$ are $k$-linear combinations of the $\,g_i,\,$ yielding the reverse containment  $\,\langle f_1,f_2\rangle\subseteq \langle g_1,g_2\rangle.\,$ Therefore $\,\langle f_1,f_2\rangle = \langle g_1,g_2\rangle$

**Remark** $\ $ Generally, as above, ideals are preserved by an invertible linear basis transformation.

Comment: If $2x^2-3y^2-5$ is in the desired ideal, what can we conclude about $2x^2-3y^2-11$? If this polynomial is in the ideal, it'd mean that the ideal contains $1$ and therefore it would contain the field $k$, this isn't necessarily true.

Comment: @Devilathor See the comments, it appears there is a typo in the problem.

Comment: Yes, you're probably right. There must be a typo.

Comment: @lukeskywalker See the edit.

Comment: @BillDubuque I fixed the typo.

Comment: @lukeskywalker Ok, I updated the answer too.